# Existence of Multivariate normal distribution $(X_1,.....,X_n)$ with $Corr(X_i,X_j) = \rho\;$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Suppose that $(X_1,.....,X_n)$ follows multivariate normal with 
$${E(X_i) = 0 \;,\; 1\le i \le n\; ;} $$
$${Var(X_i) = 1\;,\; 1\le i \le n\; ;} $$
$${Corr(X_i,X_j) = \rho\;;\;1\le i\;\neq j \le n\;  ;}$$
for $ some\; 0\le \rho < 1$.

 Show that for any ${\rho\in [0,1),(X_1,.....,X_n)}$ as
above exist, but not necessarily for $\rho\in (-1,0]$.

---

I thought of doing it using density function of multivariate normal 
That is,if density of
$(X_1,.....,X_n)$ is g(x) where $x=(x_1,...x_n) \in \mathbb{R^n}$
$${{g(x)=\frac{1}{{(2\pi)^\frac n2}\sqrt{\det\Sigma}}e^{-\frac12 x^T\Sigma^{-1}x},1(x\in \mathbb{R^n})\;;}}$$

where $\Sigma =
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & \rho &\cdots&\cdots &\rho \\
    \rho & 1& \ddots &&\rho  \\
    \vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots &\vdots\\
    \rho&&&1&\rho\\
    \rho &\cdots&&\rho&1\\
    \end{bmatrix}
_{n\times n}$

${\det\Sigma = (1+(n-1)\rho){(1-\rho)}^{n-1}}
$

I further thought that as $\det\Sigma$ need to be $\ge 0$ we can come up with some conditions that $\rho$ need to satisfy.But I didn't get anything useful.
Maybe my thought process was entirely wrong.
Anyway I would be thankful for any help

Comment: Perhaps stop the craziness with enlarged fonts?

Comment: I wrote the density in enlarged fonts,so that it is more legible.the problem with your edit is that we have to strain our eyes to read the density especially the exponential part.I prefer not to strain thats all

Comment: Quite bad idea. If you have doubts, look around you on the site and wonder why nobody does it.

Comment: Why is what so? Why is it a terrible idea to add `\LARGE` and `\large` everywhere randomly? If you are truly interested in understanding why, perhaps follow the suggestion in my previous comment. Re the exponential part, simply use `\exp(...)` instead of `e^{...}`.

Comment: Ok thanks.As I mentioned before this was my first time .So sorry for the inconvenience if any

Answer (score 1):

Here's the idea: let $e$ be the n-dim *standard* normal, then a linear transformation of $e$, say $X=\mu+Ae$ is again multivariate normal (prove it by using, say, characteristic functions for multivariate distributions) whose covariance is clearly
 $AA^T$. Now what $A$ can satisfy your requirement?

To elaborate: for existence for rho in [0, 1), rewrite the required *correlation* matrix as
$$C=\rho 11^T + (1-\rho)I$$
And therefore the required covariance matrix is just 
$$\Sigma=vCv^T,\quad\text{where}\,v=[\sigma(X_1)^2,\cdots \sigma(X_n)^2]^T.$$
which is positive definite and admits a non-singular Cholesky decomposition.

<strike>For $\rho\in(-1,0]$, $C$ isn't even positive semidefinite (proof easy), and therefore cannot be a correlation matrix.</strike>

Edit: sorry the last statement is wrong. Whether or not $C$ is positive semidefinite seems to depend on how large $\rho$ is. Actually, your required distribution exists *if and only if* the correlation matrix $C$ is semi-positive definite (in which case a Cholesky decomposition is possible). I'm talking *only if* because correlation matrix *must* be PSD.

For $\rho<0$, when does $C$ fail to be PSD? When there exists a non zero $x\in\Bbb R^n$ such that
$$x^TCx = \rho (1^T x)^2 + (1-\rho)\|x\|^2 < 0$$
Or
$$|1^Tx| / \|x\|> \left(\frac{1 + |\rho|}{|\rho|}\right)^{1/2}.$$
But since $x\mapsto 1^Tx$ is a bounded linear map, this cannot happend with a too small $|\rho|$ (in which case RHS would be too large). Indeed, the above inequality has solution if and only if the *matrix norm* (spectrual radius, namely) $\|(x\mapsto 1^Tx)\| > \left(\frac{1 + |\rho|}{|\rho|}\right)^{1/2}$.

Comment: so $\Sigma=AA^T$.For this to happen $\Sigma$ must be a positive definite matrix -By cholesky decomposition.Is that what u meant

Comment: Yes please see edit.

Comment: thanks @viv.Yours was a more general proof and I appreciate your help.If u find my question acceptable can u please up vote it.I am a newbie and I lack in reputation that's why.I am sorry to bother – Amelia 1 min ago   edit

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut sorry you're right. If rho is a small negative number, then it's still positive semidefinite because $11^T$ is a bounded linear operator.

Answer (score 1):

The $\Sigma$ you desire can be written as $(1-\rho)I + \rho J$ where $I$ is the identity matrix and $J$ is the matrix of all $1$s. Can you compute the eigenvalues of $\Sigma$ now, and state a condition for $\Sigma\succeq 0$?

> The eigenvectors of $J$ are the all ones vector (with eigenvalue $n$) and the vectors orthogonal to the all ones vector (with eigenvalue $0$). Thus the eigenvalues of $\Sigma$ are $1-\rho + n\rho$ and $1 - \rho$. So if $\rho \in [0, 1)$, these eigenvalues are nonnegative so $\Sigma \succeq 0$. If $\rho \in (-1, 0]$, then you can find an $n$ such that $1 - \rho + n \rho < 0$ so $\Sigma \not \succeq 0$.

Comment: Actually, unless each Xi has unit variance, the correlation matrix isn't the same as the covariance matrix. (They are, up to a scaling, though)

Comment: I get the point that eigen values of $\Sigma\; are\; (1-\rho + n\rho)\;and \rho\; $.

Comment: after that can u please check if my reasoning is correct

Comment: so for $\Sigma$ to be semi positive definite all its eigen values must be $\ge$ 0.Thus $\rho\;\le\;1$ and $\rho \ge\frac{-1}{n-1}$ for any value of n.Thus if $n\to \infty$ then$\rho\ge 0$

Comment: @Amelia See my edit.

Comment: @Vim I never mentioned a correlation matrix in my answer. And in OP's question, the $X_i$ do have unit variance, so the matrix in OP's question is indeed the covariance matrix.

Comment: okay @angryavian thanks for the edit.Its been helpful

Comment: @angryavian if u find my question acceptable can u please up vote it.I am a newbie and I lack in reputation that's why.I am sorry to bother